# BPEL Apache ODE .deployed file

Tags: eclipse, bpel, apache-ode

I have created a basic helloworld.bpel process file in eclipse in BPEL project and tried to deploy it Apache ODE. So I followed the steps in this link 
   [Apache ODE Eclipse BPEL guide](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/developing-simple-bpel-project-eclipse-bpel-designer-plugin-wso2-bps-bpel-exporter-plugin).

But in the later stages, after putting the relevant files in WEB-INF folder and running the APACHE ODE the expected .deployed file was not created. And Apache ODE is not detecting the same in ODE browser when I use `localhost:8080/ode/processes`.

When I tried to launch ODE server in eclipse, I am getting the following errors.
Firstly, this was the error that I got.
"Another instance of derby may have booted into the database"
 Then I restarted Apache Tomcat in services.msc. Then that error stopped showing.

Now this is the error I am stuck with.
"Schema SA does not exist"

```
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
13:54:26,099 WARN  [GeronimoConnectionEventListener] connectionErrorOccurred called with null
  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist
  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown     Source)
  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message or stacktrace in the Tomcat log?

Comment: Tomcat is only showing "starting catalina" and "stoping catalina". But the derby log is showing that "another instance of derby may have already booted the database". I have absolutely no idea on derby database

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are some problems with the embedded derby database. I'd try to completely redeploy ODE so that the database is extracted from the .war again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute Eclipse or NetBeans as Administrator.